# model calls in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Can we make `model calls` only from `controller`? 
I make model calls from view also, is it wrong to do so. 
Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well although it's possible, it's really encouraged to do this from the controller and pass the data to the view.

Why? Because heavier calculations such as database request will make the site load funny.

You might first load opening of page, then menu, then the contest takes half a second to pop up due to query being run inside rendering, and not before.

**So basic practice:**
Let the controller run the heavy stuff, and render the view file simply with given data and avoid rendering too much of it's on.

Comment: The only thing i'd add is that you should keep your db based code out of the controller and in a model.

Answer (score 0):

> The Controller serves as an intermediary between the Model, the View,
>   and any other resources needed to process the HTTP request and
>   generate a web page.
>   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html#together

In the MVC structure, the Model is the part that deals with data/database, view are designs/layouts, and controllers are the intermediary between the model and the view.

To answer your question, the Model and the View should never be directly connected in any sense. CodeIgniter may allow you to do so, but it is not what MVC is made for.

You may want to read a little more about MVC structure as a whole